# C - What is a proper way to loop inside a system() function?

Tags: c, bash

Im converting some of my old .pcd images to jpeg using the [pcdtojpeg](http://pcdtojpeg.sourceforge.net/Home.html) solution. Since I have a lot of pictures Im penning up a C program to automate the process.
I have moderate C# experience but still new to C.

**Here is what Im currently at with some placeholder magicnumbers:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i=0;

for (i=0; i<90; i++)
{

    if(i<10)
    {       
    system("sudo ./pcdtojpeg img000%d.pcd", i);
    }

    else
    {
    system("sudo ./pcdtojpeg img00%d.pcd", i);
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

The compiler outputs an error defining too many arguments to the system function as it may not take any.

I've googled for plenty of documentation around the web like [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) and linux.die.net but haven't found any answers how to properly iterate inside the system() function in C.

I am running

> GCC 4.8.0
>
> Linux 3.9.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I think, using a simple shell script would be a more suitable solution here.

Comment: why sudo? and what about a command line like `ls *.pcd|xargs -n1 ./pcdtojpeg` or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to "iterate inside `system()`". What you want to do, is iterate *around* `system()`, so that you call it multiple times. Your code already does this. The missing part is how to format the command to be different on each call.

For this, you should use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
char buf[1024];

snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "sudo ./pcdtojpeg img%03d.pcd", i);
system(buf);
```

The process of using `%`-codes to format a string is not something that is built into the C language like your code seems to expect. It's simply a convention implemented by a set of (library) functions, like `printf()` and `snprintf()`.

The `%03d` formatting code means "insert a decimal number from an `int`, and pad it using zeroes on the left so that the width becomes 3 digits, total". Thus, no `if` is needed for this.

Comment: `if (i < 10)` is also not needed, you can do the same with parameters of snprintf/sprintf

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you could even replace `000%d` with `%.4d` and drop the `if (i < 10)`.

Comment: @eis True, I implemented that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a bunch unwind, Tim and eis. I managed to come up with a suitable result and could convert my files with a breeze.

Answer (score 4):

Seconding Maxim Skurydin's comment here.

Your C code is a simple loop *around shell calls*.

In this case, C is the wrong technology to use. Use a shell script instead, and lose the `sudo` because you should *never* have to use that except for system administration purposes:

```
for id in $(seq -f %04.f 0 89)
do
    ./pcdtojpeg img${id}.pcd
done
```

Quicker done, *much* easier to comprehend and update if necessary.

(ShinTakezou did beat me to an even simpler solution, if the files you want to touch can be collected with a pattern-matching `ls`.)

Comment: Agreed, C is the wrong tool for the job. However, if this is a small part of a larger project then @unwind's answer is better.

Comment: @ams: Hmmm... I`d consider *any* use of `system()` (other than for experimental / demonstration purposes) to be a code smell.

Comment: Doing this with shell script ties the code to a platform which has compatible shell. If it is an actual app, this is a bad idea, it creates dependency not just `pcdtojpeg` binary (or whatever the actual external program), it also creates dependency to a particular shell environment.

Comment: @hyde: Doing this with C creates a dependency on a C compiler... anyways, the question mentioned a one-shot, personal-use problem on a Linux box, so I'd consider portability to be secondary.

Comment: @DevSolar Using `system()` to run the kind of program as `pcdtojpeg` is is not code smell, IMO. Often it might be a good option to use whatever library directly, but that has its own problems (licenses, compatibility with the library version, more dependencies for building the app from sources), so using `system()` is IMO completely valid alternative, as long as it is done right.

Comment: @DevSolar: `system()` is more portable than doing `fork`, `exec`, `wait`. If you need to call an external program, and are ok with the output going to the user, then `system` is the right tool for the job. That said, you need to be doing more than just this for C to be the right tool for the job.

Comment: @DevSolar To clarify, using C for what the question code does is not good, and shell script is, 100% agree with that. I was commenting on a more general level.

Comment: I think you meant to use `seq -f %04.f` instead of `seq -f $04.f`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I initially started to write this piece of code in C so it could also be used in Windows environment with minimal dependencies. Pure shell script would definately be better for strictly bash environment.

Comment: @Dreeri: In this case I strongly recommend [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com). Personally, I consider a Windows machine without Cygwin installation to be crippled. (See ShinTakezou's solution, which should be impossible to beat in simplicity.) ;-)